# AirDrop no-response from MacBook to iPhone

Tags: airdrop

MacBook Air M1 2020 + iPhone12 Pro Max

**AirDrop from iPhone to MacBook works well.**

**Handoff in both directions works well.** (Although I didn't know whether they were acting in similar ways)

The only problem is that when I want to airdrop a file **from MacBook to iPhone**, I can see my iPhone's figure, however with no-clicking-response neither in Mac nor in iPhone.

I tried to toggle the bluetooth and WiFi in both devices but the issue still exists.
I tried to restart both devices but the issue still exists.

[image: AirDrop from MacBook to iPhone doesn't work]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bugs has been fixed after I quit Proxifer completely

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Bluetooth, Wi-Fi, and AirDrop enabled. To enable it: "Settings" → "Basic" → "AirDrop" → "For all".

If you already have everything set up like this and AirDrop refuses to cooperate, then disable all items and then enable them again.